# "Global" groups without AD

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to create a "global" group, which I can use to grant access to different site collections.
I.e.: I can give readers rights to collections 1 and 3 and no rights to collection 2.

Is it somehow possible?
I tried to create the group in CA, but I can't see it in the groups management.

Comment: Corrected some grammar and some formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create such groups as SharePoint groups have site collection scope. When your create the same group (with the same name) in two site collections they are still different (have different IDs). Only AD groups can be used across several different site collections.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, I made entrance collection with sub sites in it - all ok.